# USB port suppressor

Tags: usb, integrated-circuit, port

I am using [SN65240PWG4](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1785927.pdf) USB PORT SUPPRESSOR.

This is a part of the schematic: (I have connected pins A (6) and B (8) to D- and D+ USB pins. C and D I must connect to the supply)

[image: Schematic]

In this [schematic](http://www.ti.com/lit/zip/sllr048) from TI those pins are counted as 2 and 4. and the pins connected to supply are 6 and 8.

Is it an error from Texas Instruments in the schematic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

It appears to be an error, but it really doesn't matter- all four inputs are the same, so long as you ground 1,3,5,7 on the 8-pin package, pins 2,4,6,8 can be interchanged with each other.